# Is there a way to set the TYPE of a push notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, push-notification

My app is now receiving push notifications from two different PHP scripts on our server. One is for new data, one is for incoming messages.

In my push's payload, can I set something that will tell my app the TYPE of the push notification?? I mean I know I can set the badge number, alert message, and sound. But is there a hidden message I can send that says "Message" or "Data" so that my app can handle each type appropriately??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can send any data outside of 'aps' key in your payload.